# How an implicit operator overload is selected by the compiler for real number literals

Tags: c#

Given the following code - which C# rule causes that a real number literal is casted to int and the first implicit operator overload is preferred instead of the second one?

```
class Dong
{
    public static implicit operator Dong(int i) { return null; }

    public static implicit operator Dong(decimal d) { return null; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var d = (Dong)123.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `123.1` is `double` value, declaring it as `123.1m` can be a workaround, and everything is works without converting to an `int`

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#evaluation-of-user-defined-conversions) article can help to figure out the order of convertion

Comment: The trouble is indeed that we're talking about an explicit conversion here: `Dong d = 123.1` will not compile because the implicit operators will not match. An explicit conversion operates according to different rules. Understanding exactly *how* is still not trivial, though: note that the code above will fail to compile if the `int` overload is removed entirely, as the compiler will refuse to convert the `double` to a `decimal`, even though an explicit conversion exists. If this is covered by the rules, I'm not clear on how.

Comment: @Jeroen something to do with an [explicit implicit conversion from double to int](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#explicit-conversions): _"For a conversion from float or double to an integral type, the processing depends on the overflow checking context (The checked and unchecked operators) in which the conversion takes place [...] In an unchecked context, the conversion always succeeds"_

Comment: @CodeCaster: that's not relevant; it just describes the semantics of converting from `double` to `int`. It says nothing about implicit vs. explicit conversion, and the semantics of the code above do not change depending on checked vs. unchecked as there is no overflow. Whether or not the conversion is "safe" or "sane" is not relevant here, thanks to the gloriously convoluted rules of C# overload/conversion resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions#processing-of-user-defined-explicit-conversions), and specifically this part:

> **Processing of user-defined explicit conversions**
>
> A user-defined explicit conversion from type S to type T is processed as follows:
>
> - Determine the types S0 and T0. If S or T are nullable types, S0 and
>   T0 are their underlying types, otherwise S0 and T0 are equal to S and
>   T respectively.
> - Find the set of types, D, from which user-defined conversion
>   operators will be considered. This set consists of S0 (if S0 is a
>   class or struct), the base classes of S0 (if S0 is a class), T0 (if
>   T0 is a class or struct), and the base classes of T0 (if T0 is a
>   class).
> - Find the set of applicable user-defined and lifted conversion
>   operators, U. This set consists of the user-defined and lifted
>   implicit or explicit conversion operators declared by the classes or
>   structs in D that convert from a type encompassing or encompassed by
>   S to a type encompassing or encompassed by T. If U is empty, the
>   conversion is undefined and a compile-time error occurs.
> - Find the most specific source type, SX, of the operators in U:
>
>   If any of the operators in U convert from S, then SX is S.
>
>   **Otherwise, if any of the operators in U convert from types that encompass S, then SX is the most encompassed type in the combined set of source types of those operators. If no most encompassed type can be found, then the conversion is ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.**
>
>   Otherwise ...

Bolded part applies; the most encompassed type here is `int` becase its implicitly convertible to `double` while `decimal` is not implicitly convertible to `double`:

> The most **encompassed type** in a set of types is the one type that is encompassed by all other types in the set. If no single type is encompassed by all other types, then the set has no most encompassed type. In more intuitive terms, the most encompassed type is the "smallest" type in the set—the one type that can be implicitly converted to each of the other types.

Comment: I got lost halfway trying to fill in all the parameters for this particular case. I think you're right but incomplete: `int` gets pulled into the set of encompassed types because an *implicit* conversion from `int` to `double` exists, and then that enables the *explicit* conversion from `double` to `int` to be considered (the incompleteness is from not describing that this happens and the `TX` conversion gets involved, so it goes `double` -> `int` -> `Dong`). But, like I said, got lost a bit halfway there.

Comment: @JeroenMostert The way I see it is as fallows: The explicit conversion `double` to `int` gets pulled in because its a user defined conversion from double (S0) to `int` which qualifies as an encompassed type of  `Dong` (D0): there is an implicit conversión from `int` to `Dong`. Similarly `double` to `decimal` applies, and then `double` to `int` is chosen because `int` is the most encompassed type. That how I understand it, but yes, its not easy and I might be wrong.

Comment: No, that's definitely not right: if you make the operators `explicit` nothing changes, and "encompassing" is defined in terms of *standard* implicit conversions. The operators of `Dong` only come into play in the final step to pick the "best" conversion. ("Best" being highly subjective: because `char` implicitly converts to `double`, an `explicit operator Dong(char d)` also gets invoked when you pass it a `double`!)

Comment: @JeroenMostert encompassing is defined in terms of *implicit* conversions, standard conversions are not part of it. Making the `Dong` conversions implicit or explicit makes no difference becuase, if you read correctly, when evaluating U, *all* user defined conversiones (implicit and explitic) are candidates.

Comment: The *definition* of encompassing (not "most encompassed type") is "if a **standard** implicit conversion exists from a type `A` to a type `B`, and if neither `A` nor `B` are `interface_types`, then `A` is said to be encompassed by `B`, and `B` is said to encompass `A`." This is why the conversions on `Dong` aren't relevant for that bit, and your statement that "`int`.. qualifies as an encompassed type of `Dong`" is wrong. (Those conversions *are* part of the set `U`, that I do not dispute.) Also, have an upvote while we're crunching on this before I forget. :-P

Comment: So the compiler will happily and silently convert from double to int using the explicit conversation operator, losing precision in the process, because there is an int to double implicit conversion operator present? That sounds strange to be honest.

Comment: `S = double, T = Dong, SX = int, TX = Dong`, `U` contains `int -> Dong` and `int -> double`, and the conversion proceeds by "`S` is not `SX`, so perform the standard explicit conversion `double -> int`", and "`T` is `TX`, so invoke `int -> Dong`". `SX` is `int` because it is "the most encompassed type in the combined set of source types of those operators [`U`]". Note that `Dong` cannot encompass or be encompassed by anything but `Dong`, because from the standard implicit conversions only the identity conversion applies.

Comment: Why is SX = int and not = double?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: and yet that's what the rules say. Note that the rules for *implicit* conversions are quite different, which is why `Dong d = 123.1` won't compile. `SX = int` because it is the most encompassed type (`double` encompasses `double` and `int`, `int` does not encompass `double`, the set `U` contains both because the conversions on `double` and `Dong` are all considered).

Comment: The rules seems to be arbitrary implemented though, I tried adding both int, uint and byte conversion operators and with int+byte, it uses int and with int+byte+uint it complains that both int and byte exists (not about uint though, this seems to just trigger the ambiguity)

Comment: Different question: Could this be a bug in the spec then? A usecase not considered? Again, if we disregard what the spec says, **should** it be legal to silently convert from A to B via C and losing precision when going from A to C? Or is the explicitness going to trump this either way? Basically "I said it was OK to lose precision, the fact that it was A-C that lost it instead of C-B is rather moot"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: There is an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`. There are no implicit conversions between `int` and `uint`. Since `int` and `uint` do not encompass each other there is no "most encompassed type" and the lookup fails. There is no arbitrariness, even if the consequences may appear that way. As to whether this behavior was fully intended this way from the beginning (it is almost certainly intended this way *now* in the spec, given the precision), it would require someone like Eric Lippert or another compiler author to appear and clarify.

Comment: Re: ambiguity, you found a slight bug/blemish in that the types reported in the ambiguity depend on the lexical order of the operators. Switch them around in the source (i.e. `uint`, `int`, `byte`) and the error message changes. I suppose there is no fully correct way to report that unless you include all the types.

Comment: Yep, I see the ordering issue now. Ignore that then, that's probably just a "resulting set contained 3 items, pick the first two and report".